# Rule fails to send email to billing address

Tags: commerce, rules, emails

I'm trying to create notification emails which are sent when the checkout has been completed. (Drupal [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module)

- I added a rule to send the email to site owner. It works.
- I created a new rule to send email to to the customer's billing address. I Used `[commerce-order:mail]` replacement pattern as suggested, but unfortunately the email fails to arrive.

What could cause this problem? I even considered add new data selectors, but couldn't find anything fitting to add.

Comment: `[commerce-order:mail]` will use the email address that is directly attached to the order, not the "billing address".

Answer (score 0):

As per one of the comments below this question (which kept showing up as a question with no answers):

> It seems that for the email field an additional field was added to customer profile form. Thus obviously it couldn't be accessed.
>
> A solution which works is to continue using the "Account information" checkout pane instead.

Credits: [Gugols](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/58537/gugols)